# How do I get this report emailed to me from this script?

Tags: linux

How do I get this report emailed to me from this script? I'm so new to Linux and it is frustrating. Below is what I have so far:

```
curmth=`date +%m`
mth=(Dec Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec)
prevmth=${mth[$((curmth - 1))]}
echo $prevmth

lastlog | grep $prevmth
```

Comment: Does your system have a configured mail subsystem? (If it's your machine and you haven't set one up, the answer's "no".)

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658283/shell-script-to-send-email ?

Comment: Chris yes I have mail configured. I just want the output of the lastlog emailed to me. Thank you waltinator I will make that site a favorite to refer to.